# Specifies the related objects to include in dynamic IEnumerable<object> results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic

I have to dynamically select from an arbitrary table :

```
IEnumerable<object> table = typeof(MyContext).GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(context, null) as IEnumerable<object>;
```

But now there is 1 more problem, I can't seem to find a way to `include` the related entities into the dynamic `table` above :

```
string relations= "relatedentity1,relatedentity2,relatedentity3"
relatedEntities = relations.Split(',');
foreach (string relatedEntity in relatedEntities)
{
    (table as ObjectQuery<object>).Include(relatedEntity); // error line
}
```

This approach is giving me this error (the `table` object is not `null`) :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Normally, this is how it's done :

```
MaterialStartingBalance = (from a in context.MaterialStartingBalance
    .Include("Warehouse")
    .Include("Account")
    .Include("Material")
    .Include("SalesOrder")
     select a).ToList();
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks alot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It really isn't. Wait I'm gonna think of some way to re-edit the question to avoid confusions

Comment: You're getting a `NullReferenceException` because there seems to be no conversion between `IEnumerable<object>` and `ObjectQuery<object>`. That's why your `as` statement fails.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I edited the question, I wasn't really asking about the error, I'm trying to find the solution!

Comment: What is the concrete type of your table?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov a table class represents an entity? I don't really understand your question. can you elaborate

Comment: This: `table = typeof(MyContext).GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(context, null)` uses reflection to get a property inside your `MyContext` class. What is the concrete type of that property?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `MyContext` is the DbContext (the database), the `property` you mentioned is an entity(a table in the database), which is a class in Entity Framework.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov and could you remove the duplicate warning please? Thanks!